# Linux system have different files/folders than the ones specified on google

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, netplan

Why does my Linux system have different files/folders than the ones specified on google? A no. of times I do not find the exact file or folder on my Ubuntu 20.04 Linux system command line when I search on Google/ StackOverflow or any other platform. For example - Need to change the network adapter from DHCP to static. Google says to make changes in /etc/network/interfaces but I don't have any interfaces folder in the /etc/network directory and the server has been running for years on DHCP

Comment: What do you mean by "on Google"? Do you just mean on various websites you find by searching with Google? They're probably not meant for Ubuntu 20.04 but some other distro or version of Ubuntu. Things change over time.

Comment: That's why packages install man pages locally.  Everything you need should be on your device... specific to the version of the software installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Things change over time.

Have you considered checking the time-stamps on documents/sites you found on google? If they're older than 2 years there's a possibility that they're out of date.

In particular: Ubuntu has started moving away from the if-up scripts and towards netplan since 17.10; since 20.04 netplan is the default. Check out `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

In other words: the problem is not the discrepancy between "Linux" and "on google", but on how you select your criteria for google searches.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a plenty of Linux distributions each with its own difference.

Search for documentation specific to your Linux distribution and release version.

For Ubuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration